# How to install FAB in ServiceMix 4.5.2

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, floating-action-button

I tried to install FAB in servicemix 4.5.2. When I tried to add the below feature

mvn:org.fusesource.fuse/fuse-fuse/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features, I got the below exception

```
Could not add Feature Repository:
java.lang.RuntimeException: URL [mvn:org.fusesource.fuse/fuse-fuse/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features] could not be resolved.
Please verify that the feature repository URL is correct and that your network connection works fine.
```

Then as suggested, I added the repo repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg. But no good things happened.

I added the feature from Fabric8 features:addUrl mvn:io.fabric8/fabric8-karaf/1.1.0.CR5/xml/features and it is successfully added. But when i install the fabric features, It is throwing below exception

```
karaf@root> features:install fabric-bundle
Error executing command: Can not resolve feature:
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
     ---------------------------
   package:(&(package=jline)(version>=2.11.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
      Fabric8 :: FAB (deprecated) :: OSGi
   package:(&(package=org.apache.karaf.shell.console)(version>=2.3.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
      Fabric8 :: FAB (deprecated) :: OSGi
   package:(&(package=org.apache.felix.fileinstall)(version>=3.3.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
      Fabric8 :: FAB (deprecated) :: OSGi
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install FAB in ServiceMix.

FAB is part of JBoss Fuse and you should use JBoss Fuse with FAB.

Mind that FAB has been deprecated in JBoss Fuse 6.2 onwards (fabric8 1.1 onwards). See

- http://fabric8.io/gitbook/faqGeneral.html

FAB is being replaced with OSGi resolver

- https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/blob/master/docs/osgiResolver.md